# TEAMBUILD: error MSB4057: The target "GetXapOutputFile" does not exist in the project

Tags: msbuild, silverlight-3.0, wcf-ria-services, tfsbuild

I'm getting this error trying to run my Build thru TeamBuild in TeamExplorer on Visual Studio 2008.

On the Build Machine I installed VS SP1, Team Explorer, Silverlight 3 tools, and RIA Services.

I can compile no problem with Visual Studio on my machine and directly on the Build Machine. But I still cant compile on thru TeamBuild because it "says" I'm missing GetXapOutputFile target.

I checked C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v3.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.Common.targets file and it does have the GetXapOutputFile target:

```
<!--
============================================================
                        GetXapOutputFile

This stand-alone target returns the name of the built xap file.It
only makes sense to call this after a build
============================================================
-->
<Target
    Name="GetXapOutputFile"
    DependsOnTargets="_CreateSLProperties" 
    Outputs="$(XapOutputFile)"
/>
```

Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: I've got the same problem and I've found reason: I've lost <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\Silverlight\$(SilverlightVersion)\Microsoft.Silverlight.CSharp.targets" /> in .csproj file

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was trying a command line build and had same issue, this solved it for me:

Properties menu of 'xxx.Web' project, 'Silverlight Application' tab, remove the current item and add it again. After that, when building..., the error will go away. But I don't know why it is.

Found here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/698689/error-msb4057-the-target-getxapoutputfile-does-not-exist-in-the-project